# can not access MovieClip properties in flashDevelop

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I know there is something I am doing wrong.  In my controls I have keydown events that control my hero. As of right now, I am trying to rotate my hero but he refuses to turn . Below is my Hero Class, my control class, and gameobject class. pretty much all the classes associate with the controls class.

```
package com.Objects 
{
    import com.Objects.GameObject;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Anthony Gordon
     */

     [Embed(source='../../../bin/Assets.swf', symbol='OuterRim')]
    public class Hero extends GameObject
    {

        public function Hero() 
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Here is my Controls class. This is the class where I am trying to rotate my hero but he doesnt. The keydown event does work cause I trace it.

```
package com.Objects 
{
    import com.Objects.Hero;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Anthony Gordon
     */
    public class Controls extends GameObject
    {
        private var aKeyPress:Array;
        public var ship:Hero;

        public function Controls(ship:Hero) 
        {
            this.ship = ship;
            IsDisplay = false;
            aKeyPress = new Array();
            engine.sr.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownListener);
            engine.sr.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpListener);
        }

        private function keyDownListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            //trace("down e.keyCode=" + e.keyCode);         
            aKeyPress[e.keyCode] = true;
            trace(e.keyCode);
        }

        private function keyUpListener(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
            //trace("up e.keyCode=" + e.keyCode);
            aKeyPress[e.keyCode]=false;
        }

        override public function UpdateObject():void
        {
            Update();
        }

        private function Update():void
        {
            if (aKeyPress[37])//Key press left
                ship.rotation += 3,trace(ship.rotation ); ///DOESNT ROtate      
        }//End Controls

    }

}
```

Here is GameObject Class

```
package com.Objects 
{
    import com.Objects.Engine;
    import com.Objects.IGameObject;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    /**
     * ...
     * @author Anthony Gordon
     */
    public class GameObject extends MovieClip implements IGameObject
    {
        private var isdisplay:Boolean = true;
        private var garbage:Boolean;
        public static var engine:Engine;
        public var layer:Number = 0;

        public function GameObject() 
        {

        }

        public function UpdateObject():void
        {

        }
        public function GarbageCollection():void
        {

        }
        public function set Garbage(garb:Boolean):void
        {
            garbage = garb;
        }
        public function get Garbage():Boolean
        {
            return garbage
        }
        public function get IsDisplay():Boolean
        {
            return isdisplay;
        }
        public function set IsDisplay(display:Boolean):void
        {
            isdisplay = display;
        }

        public function set Layer(l:Number):void
        {
            layer = l;
        }
        public function get Layer():Number
        {
            return layer
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I am guessing you have come from a C/C++/C# background? Seeing capitals in package names, methods and getter/setters is very alien. Only time I have seen that in an AS3 environment was a C# coder dabbled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `keyUpListener` and `keyDownListener` methods aren't calling the `UpdateObject` function.

Comment: I'm with Ross, I would confirm that engine.sr is actually dispatching the events.. and also not relying on Bubbling?

Answer (score 0):

Try listening for your `KeyboardEvent` on `stage` instead of `engine.sr` (not sure what that is)

If you put them on anything other than the stage you will need to click that specific thing first to give it focus for the events to work.

Also, the line:

```
 ship.rotation += 3,trace(ship.rotation );
```

in your `Control` class looks a bit broken.

Comment: I thought the same thing about that line, but it turns out that it's valid syntax.  Had NO idea, at all.

Comment: Yes, its valid, I use the same technique the rare times I actually use a for loop. `for ( var i:uint = 0, len:uint = myArray.length; i < len; i++ ) {}` saves doing a double lookup on the length variable and it doesn't make the line count increase.